# A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Tags: unity3d, unity

Quería ver que esta pasando con mi script, básicamente lo que quiero es como en todos los fps shooters quiero mover la cámara con el mouse.

El error es:

> Assets/camera.cs(17,10): erros CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

```
 public class Camera : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Camera cam;
        public float mouseHorizontal = 3.0f;
        public float mouseVertical = 2.0f;
        public float minRotation = -65.0f;
        public float maxRotation = 60.0f;
        float h_mouse, v_mouse;
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        h_mouse = mouseHorizontal * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        v_mouse += mouseVertical * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        v_mouse = Mathf.Clamp(v_mouse, minRotation, maxRotation);
        cam.transform.localEulerAngels = new Vector3(-v_mouse, 0, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que cerraste el alcance de la clase en la línea siguiente a `float h_mouse, v_mouse;` al añadir un `}`, esto está dejando a la función `Start` y `Update` fuera de tu clase y por lo tanto dentro del espacio de nombres `namespace` de ahí viene el error.

Para solucionarlo tendrías que mover el símbolo al final de tu documento, asegúrate que cada `namespace`, `class` y función (`void Start()` por ejemplo) se abra y cierre correctamente ({ y }) para evitar este error en el futuro.

Así quedaría el código arreglado (Con el espacio de nombres y las declaraciones `using` omitidas como en tu ejemplo):

```
public class Camera : MonoBehaviour {
    public Camera cam;
    public float mouseHorizontal = 3.0f;
    public float mouseVertical = 2.0f;
    public float minRotation = -65.0f;
    public float maxRotation = 60.0f;
    float h_mouse, v_mouse;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        h_mouse = mouseHorizontal * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        v_mouse += mouseVertical * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        v_mouse = Mathf.Clamp(v_mouse, minRotation, maxRotation);
        cam.transform.localEulerAngels = new Vector3(-v_mouse, 0, 0);
    }
}
```